# How to handle "Login not possible (error in license check) in SAP GUI

Tags: sap-gui

I have installed the sapse/abap-program-trial docker package on an Azure VM. That part looked ok and the SAPGUI I downloaded does connect.

When I attempt any login I get this message:

> **Logon not possible (error in license check)**

Is that due to a missing license for the front-end or the back-end?

Any help would be greatly apprecieated.

Comment: Backend license. NB: frontend SAP GUI can be obtained and used only if you have a SAP software backend license too.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. Whenever you get the “Logon not possible (Error in license check)” message on logon screen, it means that the license in your SAP system has expired.

Comment: So it's on the back-end. I followed all of the instructions for creating the sapse\abap-platform-trial docker install.  There is even a question about accepting the SAP license to which you have to type "Accept". I'm not sure where to go from here.